# Im getting very low fps on my phone in simple game

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, frame-rate, urp

I have a simple game with less than 20 batches and 2ms cpu main. But in build i have about 10 fps on my phone. Im using urp and shader graph.

Here is a screenshots

[image: image1],

[image: image2]

I tried to add some Unity assets to optimize my game, but it didn't work. Also, I tried to build my game on older versions and without URP, but this didn't work too.

Comment: Have you tried changing quality settings in project settings?

Comment: @Obscure021 yes

Comment: What phone are you trying it on? If you run an entirely empty scene, what framerate do you get?

Comment: Try to reduce vertices, or tris by optimizing the models.

Comment: @Obscure021 i have already minimun of vertices for pleasing to the eyes

Comment: @Bart Samsung a31 2020 year. I get no more than 30

Comment: @Smile3329 Does it stay around 30 like in between 28 - 32 but mostly 30? If so, then try turning vsync off.

Comment: Note that vsyncCount is ignored on mobile platforms. You want to use Application.targetFramerate instead. Your mobile phone's screen has a maximum refresh rate of 60Hz, so set the targetFramerate to 60 and see what happens.

Comment: @Bart I set Application.targetFrameRate to 60, but fps without transparent water is 29-30. With water 10-14 fps.

Comment: @Obscure021 i get fps only under 30. No more than 30. VSync is turned off